# Geofencing not triggered when user exit that fence?(P.S.when it is already on same area it triggered)

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

So Far :-

When user in same(under fence area) it gives notification "user enters in area" is ok.But same user leave fence area its not notified.

This is my code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener,
    ResultCallback<Status> 
{

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private GoogleMap map;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private Location lastLocation;

    private TextView textLat, textLong;

    private MapFragment mapFragment;

    private static final String NOTIFICATION_MSG = "NOTIFICATION MSG";

    // Create a Intent send by the notification
    public static Intent makeNotificationIntent(Context context, String msg) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_MSG, msg);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
        textLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lon);

        // initialize GoogleMaps
        initGMaps();

        // create GoogleApiClient
        createGoogleApi();
    }

    // Create GoogleApiClient instance
    private void createGoogleApi() {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGoogleApi()");
        if (googleApiClient == null) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Call GoogleApiClient connection when starting the Activity
        googleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Disconnect GoogleApiClient when stopping Activity
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.geofence: {
                startGeofence();
                return true;
            }
            case R.id.clear: {
                clearGeofence();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private final int REQ_PERMISSION = 999;

    // Check for permission to access Location
    private boolean checkPermission() {
        Log.d(TAG, "checkPermission()");
        // Ask for permission if it wasn't granted yet
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }

    // Asks for permission
    private void askPermission() {
        Log.d(TAG, "askPermission()");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                REQ_PERMISSION
        );
    }

    // Verify user's response of the permission requested
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult()");
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_PERMISSION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission granted
                    getLastKnownLocation();

                } else {
                    // Permission denied
                    permissionsDenied();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // App cannot work without the permissions
    private void permissionsDenied() {
        Log.w(TAG, "permissionsDenied()");
        // TODO close app and warn user
    }

    // Initialize GoogleMaps
    private void initGMaps() {
        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    // Callback called when Map is ready
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady()");
        map = googleMap;
        map.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapClick(" + latLng + ")");
        //markerForGeofence(latLng);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMarkerClickListener: " + marker.getPosition());
        return false;
    }

    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    // Defined in mili seconds.
    // This number in extremely low, and should be used only for debug
    private final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000;
    private final int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 900;

    // Start location Updates
    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        Log.i(TAG, "startLocationUpdates()");
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

        if (checkPermission())
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged [" + location + "]");
        lastLocation = location;
        writeActualLocation(location);
    }

    // GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks connected
    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnected()");
        getLastKnownLocation();
        recoverGeofenceMarker();
        startGeofence();
    }

    // GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks suspended
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended()");
    }

    // GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener fail
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionFailed()");
    }

    // Get last known location
    private void getLastKnownLocation() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastKnownLocation()");
        if (checkPermission()) {
            lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
            if (lastLocation != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "LasKnown location. " +
                        "Long: " + lastLocation.getLongitude() +
                        " | Lat: " + lastLocation.getLatitude());
                writeLastLocation();
                startLocationUpdates();
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "No location retrieved yet");
                startLocationUpdates();
            }
        } else askPermission();
    }

    private void writeActualLocation(Location location) {
        textLat.setText("Lat: " + location.getLatitude());
        textLong.setText("Long: " + location.getLongitude());
        markerLocation(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    }

    private void writeLastLocation() {
        writeActualLocation(lastLocation);
    }

    private Marker locationMarker;

    private void markerLocation(LatLng latLng) {
        Log.i(TAG, "markerLocation(" + latLng + ")");
        String title = latLng.latitude + ", " + latLng.longitude;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title(title);
        if (map != null) {
            if (locationMarker != null)
                locationMarker.remove();
            locationMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
            float zoom = 14f;
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
            map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
    }

    // Start Geofence creation process
    private void startGeofence() {
        Log.i(TAG, "startGeofence()");
        Geofence geofence = createGeofence();
        GeofencingRequest geofenceRequest = createGeofenceRequest(geofence);
        addGeofence(geofenceRequest);
    }

    private static final long GEO_DURATION = 60 * 60 * 1000;
    private static final String GEOFENCE_REQ_ID = "My Geofence";
    private static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 200.0f; // in meters

    // Create a Geofence
    private Geofence createGeofence() {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofence");
        return new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(GEOFENCE_REQ_ID)
                .setCircularRegion(18.478122, 73.890158, GEOFENCE_RADIUS)
                .setExpirationDuration(GEO_DURATION)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .build();
    }

    // Create a Geofence Request
    private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest(Geofence geofence) {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofenceRequest");
        return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
                .addGeofence(geofence)
                .build();
    }

    private PendingIntent geoFencePendingIntent;
    private static final int GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE = 0;

    private PendingIntent createGeofencePendingIntent() {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofencePendingIntent");
        if (geoFencePendingIntent != null)
            return geoFencePendingIntent;

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTrasitionService.class);
        return PendingIntent.getService(
                this, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    // Add the created GeofenceRequest to the device's monitoring list
    private void addGeofence(GeofencingRequest request) {
        Log.d(TAG, "addGeofence");
        if (checkPermission())
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                    googleApiClient,
                    request,
                    createGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onResult: " + status);
        if (status.isSuccess()) {
            drawGeofence();
        } else {
            // inform about fail
        }
    }

    // Draw Geofence circle on GoogleMap
    private Circle geoFenceLimits;

    private void drawGeofence() {
        Log.d(TAG, "drawGeofence()");

        if (geoFenceLimits != null)
            geoFenceLimits.remove();

        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
                .center(new LatLng(18.478122, 73.890158))
                .strokeColor(Color.argb(50, 70, 70, 70))
                .fillColor(Color.argb(100, 150, 150, 150))
                .radius(GEOFENCE_RADIUS);
        geoFenceLimits = map.addCircle(circleOptions);
    }

    private final String KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT = "GEOFENCE LATITUDE";
    private final String KEY_GEOFENCE_LON = "GEOFENCE LONGITUDE";

    // Saving GeoFence marker with prefs mng
    private void saveGeofence() {
        Log.d(TAG, "saveGeofence()");
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

        // editor.putLong(KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT, Double.doubleToRawLongBits(geoFenceMarker.getPosition().latitude));
        // editor.putLong(KEY_GEOFENCE_LON, Double.doubleToRawLongBits(geoFenceMarker.getPosition().longitude));
        editor.apply();
    }

    // Recovering last Geofence marker
    private void recoverGeofenceMarker() {
        drawGeofence();
    }

    // Clear Geofence
    private void clearGeofence() {
        Log.d(TAG, "clearGeofence()");
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(
                googleApiClient,
                createGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                    // remove drawing
                    removeGeofenceDraw();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void removeGeofenceDraw() {
        Log.d(TAG, "removeGeofenceDraw()");
    }

}
```

To get notification:-

```
public class GeofenceTrasitionService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = GeofenceTrasitionService.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final int GEOFENCE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;

    public GeofenceTrasitionService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        // Handling errors
        if ( geofencingEvent.hasError() ) {
            String errorMsg = getErrorString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode() );
            Log.e( TAG, errorMsg );
            return;
        }

        int geoFenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
        // Check if the transition type is of interest
        if (geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT ) {
            // Get the geofence that were triggered
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTrasitionDetails(geoFenceTransition, triggeringGeofences );
            // Send notification details as a String
            sendNotification( geofenceTransitionDetails );
        }
    }

    private String getGeofenceTrasitionDetails(int geoFenceTransition, List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {
        // get the ID of each geofence triggered
        ArrayList<String> triggeringGeofencesList = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences ) {
            triggeringGeofencesList.add( geofence.getRequestId() );
        }

        String status = null;
        if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT )
            status = "Exiting ";
        return status + TextUtils.join( ", ", triggeringGeofencesList);
    }

    private void sendNotification( String msg ) {
        Log.i(TAG, "sendNotification: " + msg );

        // Intent to start the main Activity
        Intent notificationIntent = MainActivity.makeNotificationIntent(
                getApplicationContext(), msg
        );

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        // Creating and sending Notification
        NotificationManager notificatioMng =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
        notificatioMng.notify(
                GEOFENCE_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                createNotification(msg, notificationPendingIntent));
    }

    // Create notification
    private Notification createNotification(String msg, PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_location)
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setContentTitle(msg)
                .setContentText("Geofence Notification!")
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        return notificationBuilder.build();
    }

    private static String getErrorString(int errorCode) {
        switch (errorCode) {
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                return "GeoFence not available";
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
                return "Too many GeoFences";
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
                return "Too many pending intents";
            default:
                return "Unknown error.";
        }
    }
}
```

As per tutorial i see:- there are 3 notification trigger
1.Enter 2.Dwell 3.Exit

I dont know how did i get notified when it leave the fence so far as in code i tried Exit.But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i understand so just need to change the function :-

```
   private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest(Geofence geofence) {
    Log.d(TAG, "createGeofenceRequest");
    return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT)
            .addGeofence(geofence)
            .build();
}
```

Here i did changed My initial trigger with Exit
**"GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT"** 
and got perfect output.

Answer (score 0):

This work for both enter and exit

```
private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest(Geofence geofence) {
    return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT|GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
            .addGeofence(geofence)
            .build();
```

Comment: Haider:-Is this work when app is in background or if app is kill.